# URLConnection getInputStream()/openStream() is slow for the first time

Tags: java, tomcat

I am executing the following line, as soon as the Tomcat server(5.5.28) is started..

```
URL  url = new URL("http://localhost:80/servlets/ConnectionCheckServlet");
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
long t=System.currentTimeMillis();
//InputStream content = (InputStream)uc.getInputStream();
InputStream content = (InputStream)url.openStream();
System.out.println("Time diff: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-t));
```

The Timediff in millisecs got printed as Time diff: 5141 (> 5 Seconds)

For the subsequent call on the same servlet or for a different servlet, the time diff is actually less than a second.

Will the first time delay, some thing to do with Tomcat intialization??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it could be due to compilation and/or caching of the servlet which could occur the first time accessed.

Comment: due to compilation:
Forgot to mention that there was no dynamic compilation.
Caching of the servlet:
Even, if I invoke a different servlet on the second time, the time taken is in milliseconds (less than a second)

Comment: There may be no dynamic compilation but you still have to consider dynamic class-loading in the JVM.  I imagine the loading of the servlet class and all dependencies takes a while.  If you find that this delay only ever happens the first time, then this is undoubtedly the cause.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Thanks a lot. I confirmed it by generating 4 Threaddumps programatically in that interval and it confirms Class loading initialization is done in that time frame. Sorry for bothering you.